# Linking classes together c++

Tags: c++, oop

So let's say that I have an 'Account' class(general bank accounts example: savings account, current account) and a 'Client' class (the client of the bank). How would I make that the client is the owner of an account?

I believe that I should do something like this, but I'm not sure:

```cpp
class Client
{
private:
    string name;
    string social_security_no;
    string email;
    string phone;
    string address;
    int trust_score;
    int client_id;

protected:
    static int next_client_id;

public:
    Client();
};

class Account
{
private:
    string acc_name;
    string iban;
    double balance;
    Client client;
    string currency;
    int acc_id;

protected:
    static int next_acc_id;

public:
    Account();
};
```

Comment: Does an account always have exactly one client? If so then the above is reasonable.

Comment: Also ask yourself, if you have an account do you want to easily know who the client is, if so then the above is reasonable. But also consider, if you have a client do you want to know what account they have? Or perhaps could they have multiple accounts, or no accounts? These possibilities are not addressed in the code above.

Comment: No, an account should not contain a **copy** of a client.

Comment: I would expect a client class to have some access to its account(s).

Comment: You also need to consider the possibility that you are storing multiple clients. Maybe you have a bank object that holds a list of clients. Then you don't want to also store the same clients in your account object. Instead use some kind of pointer or reference to the client that is stored in the bank object,. Another possibility would be to store the client id in the account object, instead of the client itself. Then you can use the id to lookup the client object.

Answer (score 1):

This reeks of homework.

Anyway, it depends how your respective `Client` or `Account` objects are stored or supposed to be stored. What is their lifetime as in how long do they have to be in memory and where are they persisted.

If this is like a database, like the topic of banking suggests, then composition is generally wrong, which is what you did as your `Account` is composed of a `Client`.
Instead you'd create the 2 objects separately them having pointers to reference each other, while you will have to maintain the objects respective lifetime to not have dangling references.
To circumvent the need for the latter you would save them inside an `std::map` under a key instead and use this key instead of a pointer, with the benefit of being able to test the map if the object under the key still exists and the drawback of having to request your objects from the map every time. Voila, a database.

If you can assume that a client always only has one account, you could give the client the account in composition. This also means the lifetimes are tied. If the Client-Object is gone, so is the Account.
The other way around, which is what you did, as your `Account` is composed of a client is also doable in the right context.
The problem here is hierarchy. By doing composition one object is always hierarchically less than the other. The objects are also inadvertently tied to one another with composition.
You have to decide which one is on top, but then the data is constricted in being used in one perspective over the other, especially abstractly.
Hence databases use keys.